# using bootstarp4 carousel slid show all data appears, how to enable each item individually appears

Tags: slideshow, bootstrap-carousel

data from database is fetched all but in slider it shows all three selected items.
three rows are select with correct content from database but it appears as mixed up all three item over each other as well the next and previous button is also not working.

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#mycarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php
            $show_slider=show_slider();
            $rows=$show_slider->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($rows as $row){?>
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row p-5">
                            <div class="mx-auto col-md-8 col-lg-6 order-lg-last">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/upload_img/product_pic/<?php echo $row['p_picture']?>" alt="<?php echo $row['p_brand']?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-0 d-flex align-items-center">
                                <div class="text-align-left align-self-center">
                                    <h1 class="h1 text-success"><b><?php echo $row['p_brand']?></b></h1>
                                    <h3 class="h2"> <?php echo $row['p_about']?></h3>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $row['p_remark']?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
    
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev text-decoration-none w-auto ps-3" href="#carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-decoration-none w-auto pe-3" href="#carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    
    </div>
    <script>
        $(".carousel .item").first().addClass("active");
    </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community; content from database appears as mixed up all three item over each other as well the next and previous button is also not working in slide show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is below code fixed my issue:

```
<div id="Scarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <?php
    $show_slider=show_slider();
    $rows=$show_slider->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php
        $i=0;

        foreach ($rows as $value){
            if ($i==0){
                echo '<li data-bs-target="#Scarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
                $i++;
            }
            else{
                echo '<li data-bs-target="#Scarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        $s=0;
        foreach ($rows as $value){
            if ($s==0){
             echo  '
            <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row p-5">
                    <div">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="./img/upload_img/product_pic/'. $value["p_picture"].'" alt="'.$value["p_picture"].'">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-align-left align-self-center">
                            <h1 class="h1 text-success"><b>'.$value["p_brand"].'</b></h1>
                            <h3 class="h2">'.$value["p_about"].'</h3>
                            <p>'.$value["p_remark"].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                ';
             $s++;
            }
            else{
                echo  '
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row p-5">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="./img/upload_img/product_pic/'. $value["p_picture"].'" alt="'.$value["p_picture"].'">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-align-left align-self-center">
                            <h1 class="h1 text-success"><b>'.$value["p_brand"].'</b></h1>
                            <h3 class="h2">'.$value["p_about"].'</h3>
                            <p>'.$value["p_remark"].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                ';
                $s++;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev text-decoration-none w-auto ps-3" href="#Scarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-decoration-none w-auto pe-3" href="#Scarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).